# How can I possibly test b_4<b_3<b_2<b_1<0 in stata?

Tags: regression-coefficients, stata

I am trying to run a test on coefficients relationship after linear regression. How can i test the following relationship: b_4<b_3<b_2<b_1<0

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/linear-regression-with-interval-constraints/